# Как правильно написать 2 цикла php foreach?

Tags: php, html

Привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее написать цикл на PHP + html разметка, ибо и за моего косяка теперь каждый item в item'e

```
$values = rwmb_meta( $field_id );
foreach ( $values as $clone ) {
    foreach ( $clone as $value ) {
        echo $value['name'];
        echo $value['address'];
        echo $value['email'];
    }
}



<div class="new-item">
  <div class="new-item__name">Здесь name над</div>
  <div class="new-item__adress">Здесь address</div>
  <div class="new-item__email">Угадайте что тут должно быть:D</div>
</div>
```

Values хранит к примеру 5 элементов у кажждого элемента свои свойства. 
Тогда надо 5 разметок .new-item что бы каждая имела свой name

Никак не могу правильно поставить структуру

Comment: `что бы каждая имела свой name` как это имя должно формироваться? Вы показали три `echo` а а итоговом html у Вас и дивы, и классы. Это Вы показали, что Вы хотите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше конечно стараться делать отдельно представление, но думаю для вашего случая должен быть вот такой код:

```
<?php
$values = rwmb_meta( $field_id );
?>

<?php foreach($values as $clone): ?>
    <div class="new-item">
    <?php foreach($clone as $value): ?>
      <div class="new-item__name"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></div>
      <div class="new-item__adress"><?php echo $value['address']; ?></div>
      <div class="new-item__email"><?php echo $value['email']; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = rwmb_meta($field_id);
foreach ($values as $clone) {
    echo '<div class="new-item">';
    foreach ($clone as $value) {
        echo '<div class="new-item__name">' . $value['name'] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="new-item__adress">' . $value['address'] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="new-item__email">' . $value['email'] . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$html = '';
$values = rwmb_meta( $field_id );
foreach ( $values as $clone ) {
    $html .= '<div class="new-item">';
    foreach ( $clone as $value ) {
        $html .= '<div class="new-item__name">'.$value['name'].'</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="new-item__name">'.$value['address'].'</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="new-item__name">'.$value['email'].'</div>';
    }
    $html .= '</div>'; // new-item
}

echo $html;
?>
```